# How to fix error with H2 plugin (version 1.4.200) when run Spring tests: JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "start_value" not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2, spock

I had to update Spring Boot starter from 2.1.4.RELEASE to  2.2.6.RELEASE, but now the integration tests are failing.

My tests are in Groovy, my application is written in Java. They runned well with previous Spring version (2.1.4).

After the update of the SpringBoot Starter version, a new error began to appear in the log when I run the integration tests:

H2 - version

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
           <version>1.4.200</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

This is the log:

```
====================== Init Spring ======================
2020-10-30 16:43:17.867  WARN 13275 --- [           main] kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint    : No meta.properties file under dir /tmp/kafka-14845506122745551840/meta.properties
2020-10-30 16:43:19.651 ERROR 13275 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl   : Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "start_value" not found [42122-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getColumnIndex(JdbcResultSet.java:3169)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.get(JdbcResultSet.java:3268)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getLong(JdbcResultSet.java:680)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getLong(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.resultSetStartValueSize(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.sequenceInformationList(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1202)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:126)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringTestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(SpringTestContextManager.java:56)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringInterceptor.interceptInitializerMethod(SpringInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMethodInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:97)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:475)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runInitializer(BaseSpecRunner.java:341)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runInitializer(BaseSpecRunner.java:336)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.initializeAndRunIteration(BaseSpecRunner.java:274)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runSimpleFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:266)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.doRunFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:260)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner$5.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:243)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:484)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:467)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:235)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runFeatures(BaseSpecRunner.java:185)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.doRunSpec(BaseSpecRunner.java:95)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner$1.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:81)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:484)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:467)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runSpec(BaseSpecRunner.java:73)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.run(BaseSpecRunner.java:64)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.run(Sputnik.java:63)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:40)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)

2020-10-30 16:43:19.949  WARN 13275 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 42122, SQLState: 42S22
2020-10-30 16:43:19.949 ERROR 13275 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column "start_value" not found [42122-200]
2020-10-30 16:43:22.920 ERROR 13275 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

My application run failed in tests, but when I start with SqlServer, it doesn't fail.

I use Spock (Groovy):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
           <version>1.3-groovy-2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
           <version>1.3-groovy-2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

The application-test.yml:

```
spring:
  profiles: test
  groovy:
    template:
      check-template-location: false
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: "jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;MODE=MSSQLServer;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
    username: sa
    password:
    platform: h2
    continue-on-error: true
    initialization-mode: embedded
    hikari:
      driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
      jdbc-url: "jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 50
          batch_versioned_data: true
          fetch_size: 100
        order_inserts: true
        order_updates: true
        new_generator_mappings: true
        show_sql: false
        format_sql: false
        connection:
          release_mode: after_transaction
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      use-new-id-generator-mappings: false
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    open-in-view: false
    generate-ddl: true
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the failing test please?

Comment: `H2Dialect` in recent Hibernate uses `SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl` with snapshot builds of upcoming H2 2.0, but not for H2 1.4.200, for your version `SequenceInformationExtractorH2DatabaseImpl` is used by H2 dialect. Such stack trace looks like wrong dialect in use or like some other obscure problem. A breakpoint in `JdbcEnvironmentImpl.sequenceInformationList()` may help to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov thank you for the reply. But I don't understand what to change, maybe change dialect?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Hibernate. But H2Dialect of Hibernate shouldn't use `SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl` with your version of H2 due to this condition: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/67fd24ecff9f9a9a2e848805c04590b4b4ee2b3e/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/H2Dialect.java#L108-L110

Answer (score 17):

Thaks to @EvgenijRyazanov! When I debug, I found that the dialect was wrong:

```
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

and I reviewd the application-test.yml and add:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

It solves my problem!

Comment: Good find. H2 used in tests instead of psql, this fixed the issue

Comment: And if someone has 'org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect' but it stopped working after Hibernate update - your H2 version is no longer supported: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/2220cf7fe5579feffb52092373c732a266ba179f

Answer (score 3):

The workaround I used was to set (in the application.yml or application.properties):

```
jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto to "create" or to "none"
```

Changing this setting solved the issue for me, but it changes the behavior of your database initialisation so it might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case the issue of miss-match between my app version and local instance of H2, which I was using in server mode.

- locally running 1.4.x
- the app was using 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Solved by upgrading h2 driver from 1.4.200 to 2.2.220.

```
  testImplementation group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '2.2.220'
```

I had this problem on Spring Boot 3.2.2 when upgrading from 3.1.2. Hibernate 6.4.1 does not support h2 versions older than 2.1.